# File managment on Azure blob storage

Tags: azure, versioning, azure-blob-storage, file-storage, security-trimming

Is there a service or a(n open-source) library that could help in programmatically manage files stored on Azure blob storage. By manage I mean search with security trimming, authorizing download, document-versioning.

I've looked online but most of the solutions are more of end-user solutions. Should I build my own layer to talk to blob storage or there's a way that can take a part of this burden off my shoulders?

A solution that could work with both cloud (blob) and on-premise storage would be great!

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "security trimming" and "authorizing download"?

Comment: By authorizing download I mean: A user of my application could only download a file which he has access to. So, even if she's given a url to a file that they are not authorized to access they shouldn't be able to download it.

Comment: By "search with security trimming" I mean: that if a user is doing a search for document with specific keywords, search results should only show the files she is authorized to access, not all relevant file/documents in the system.

Comment: AFAIK, there's no library/service which could do that. Blob storage service is simply an object storage and does not have the features you're looking for. These would be something you have to implement yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any such library. That being said the storage platform does include the underlying capabilities upon which you could implement these features. For example, for authorizing access to objects you could issue [SAS tokens](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/) to authorized users. For document versioning you can create [snapshots](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee691971.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) on objects etc.